# Google maps API : overlaying areas

Tags: google-maps, overlay, gis

I'm pretty new to mapping tools. I have a project to overlay wind energy data onto maps. A particular Glatlng has a particular wind rank value.**I need to shade a region using this data.**
I've referred the API tutorial by google, but I'm finding it difficult to know whether I'm going in the right direction. 
I'm just asking you guys to give me the right direction to work on this project. 
Please help me out.

Thank you

Comment: Need a bit more clarification. What does a region mean in this case? You want to put down a marker? You want to shade a circle or polygon? Something else?

Comment: i am wondering if you already have polygon that you want to shade, or converting data at discrete geographic point into shaded region is also a part of question...?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a heatmap. Have a look at: http://code.google.com/p/gheat/

There is a huge difference in the approaches whether you need this rarely, or high-performance for thousands of users.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to you compose kml and then overlay on top of google map, like second example here,  [KMLLayers](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#KMLLayers), in particular [layer-kml.html](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml.html).   KML is documented [here](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html), and since it is open source there are tools to convert data into kml.  it is not terribly hard to compose it on your own.  good part of this aporoach is that you  can get away with lots of javascript programming and stick with markup language.

If your data is already gridded an image, you may consider showing it as raster overlay with transparency.

I am not terribly experienced with google map so there may be more convenient ways, so look around too.